# How to return html page in Microservices architecture

Tags: spring, microservices

Slowly but surely I adopt microservices approach. So I created some microservices always returning json.

But now I was thinking to convert a monolith into microservies. I noticed every endpoint returns a html page, namely a string interpreted by Thymeleaf as a html page.

So how can I transform that to microservice ? Should the service still return this html page ?

Comment: Hey @andrea19, welcome to stackoverflow!

This is a very broad question and to be able to help you it's better to add some code and show your use case.

Comment: What is not clear about this question ? Is Microservice more like api meaning only return json or xml  or can it also return html page.

Comment: You are moving multiple problems here. First you seem to think Microservices must only return Json or XML. But you don't say why you think so. Second you refer to spring MVC implementation, which is a different question. Third you don't describe what your monolith does, making it impossible to give specific advice. Forth is to broad as many other technologies exist to provide user interface, not just thymeleaf rendered html. If you only want to know if Microservices can return html, the answer is just "yes", and it's not a very useful question.

Comment: Also note this site is better for get general architecture advice: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Microservices Architecture is an architectural style that structures an application as a collection of services. In other words, it's something like separating the big system we have into subsystems that connecting and calling each other.

So, each microservice has system internal calls (microservice calls another one) and external system calls (call from a user through his web browser). Microservices call each other using APIs. But when it comes to the external calls, **it might respond with a JSON or HTML** as you like as any normal system.